# Combine Tax Archive and Meta_Query in WP_Query

Tags: wp-query, advanced-taxonomy-queries, multi-taxonomy-query

Is there a way to instantiate a WP_Query object—filtered by post_meta and taxonomy_meta—within the loop of which I can have access to both *post* and *taxonomy-archive* methods (like `the_excerpt` and `get_cat_name`)?

Want to return all "featured" posts *and* taxonomy archives to display details from.

This gets all the featured posts:

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'post_type', 
'post_status' => 'publish',
'meta_query'  => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'featured-meta-checkbox',
                'value' => 'yes'
            )
        ),
'fields' => 'id',
'posts_per_page' => -1
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
// Some HTML
if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
// display content
endif; endwhile;
// More HTML
```

Then I am looping through taxonomy terms

```
$taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies( (object) array( 'post_type' => 'post_type' ) );
$terms = get_terms( $taxonomy );
foreach( $terms as $term ) : 
    if (get_term_meta( $term->term_id, 'featured-meta-checkbox', true ) == 'yes'):
// Here we can use
    get_cat_name( $term->term_id );
    get_category_link( $term->term_id );
    category_description($term->term_id);
```

And I can probably even find a way to display the `category_thumbnail` that the parent theme provides (or use [Taxonomy Images](https://wordpress.org/plugins/taxonomy-images/)).

So I end up with a slider (in this case) displaying featured posts, each with an image, excerpt, title, followed by title, (trimmed) description and probably image for featured categories.

But this approach is inelegant, and also puts all of the Taxonomy Archives *after* the featured posts. Ideally I'd like to be able to intermingle the posts and archive, although I'm not sure based on what criteria yet.

UPDATE: For what it's worth, the following is what pulled in the category image provided by the Total theme:

```
<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( WPEX_Term_Thumbnails::get_term_thumbnail_id($term->term_id) ); ?>;
```

Basically using a static method from Total's `WPEX_Term_Thumbnails` class.

Comment: You've described what you have and don't want, but I'm not sure what results you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Hmmm. Great point. Will update question.

Comment: @Milo I hope the update clarifies things.